# Flutter: Text to Voice Tamil language is support?

Tags: flutter, dart, text-to-speech

I have trying to convey my text to speech tamil language but it not support any other way is there?

Am using : flutter_tts package

my code:

```
speak() async {    
final languages = await Tts.getAvailableLanguages();
var isGoodLanguage = await Tts.isLanguageAvailable("ta");
print(isGoodLanguage);
await Tts.setLanguage("tamil");
Tts.speak('வாழ்ந்த காலம்: 2 ஆம் நூறாண்டு முதல் 8 நூற்றாண்டு வரை');  }
```

But it's not working anyone tried with tamil text to voice please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's supported in the engine but not it the TTS. [follow it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527186/how-to-set-tamil-voice-in-tts-android-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

If "ta" is a supported language code on your device (You should receive the list of supported language codes when you run `await Tts.getAvailableLanguages()`), you should use that to set the language rather than "tamil".

Change: `await Tts.setLanguage("tamil");`
To: `await Tts.setLanguage("ta");`